# [asyncssh]: Reverse ssh tunnels with python asyncssh

Tags: paramiko, python-asyncio

I am looking to use asyncssh with python3.7 (asyncio)

**Here is what I want to build:**

A remote device would be running a client that does a call-home to a centralized server. I want the server to be able to execute commands on client using reverse ssh tunnels on the incoming connection. I cannot use forward ssh (regular ssh) because the client could be behind NAT and server might not know the address of the client. I prefer client doing a call-home and then server managing the client.

The program for a POC should use python3 + an async implementation of ssh. I see asyncssh as the only viable choice (please suggest if you have an alternate):

**Client**:  Connect to server and accepts reverse ssh tunnels to be opened on same outbound connection

**Server**: Accepts connection from client and keeps the session open. The server then opens reverse ssh tunnel to the client. For e.g. the server program should open 3 reverse ssh tunnnels on the incoming connection. Each of these tunnels would run one command ['ls', 'sleep 30 && date', 'sleep 5 && cat /proc/cpuinfo']

Server program should print the received response for each of these commands (one should come back amost immediately, other after 5 and other after 30).

I looked at the documentation, and I could not see examples of using multiple reverse ssh tunnels.

Anyone has experience using this? Can you point me to examples?

Answer (score 0):

Developer of asyncssh has provided an example:

As of now, this is in develop branch. I have tested it and it does the job perfectly!

https://asyncssh.readthedocs.io/en/develop/#reverse-direction-example

[If you are checking this after a while, you might find it in master documentation.]